# Change table structure using dynamic SQL and not knowing the number of attributes in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, normalization

If I have a table like this (where I do not know the name of the columns and How many are there, in this example there are 5 attributes, with 20 rows:

```
x1  x2   x3   x4   x5    
----------------------------
438 498  3625 3645 5000 
438 498  3625 3648 5000
438 498  3625 3629 5000
437 501  3625 3626 5000
438 498  3626 3629 5000
439 498  3626 3629 5000
440 5000 3627 3628 5000
444 5021 3631 3634 5000
451 5025 3635 3639 5000
458 5022 3640 3644 5000
465 525  3646 3670 5000
473 533  3652 3676 5000
481 544  3658 3678 5000
484 544  3661 3665 5000
484 532  3669 3662 2945
482 520  3685 3664 2952
481 522  3682 3661 2955
480 525  3694 3664 2948
481 515  5018 3664 2956
479 5000 3696 3661 2953
```

How would you get something like this
(`5 columns * 20 rows = 100 rows` where every 20 rows we have a column of previous table)

```
Id Ordinal Name Value
----------------------------
1   1   x1  438
2   1   x1  438
3   1   x1  438
4   1   x1  437
5   1   x1  438
6   1   x1  439
7   1   x1  440
8   1   x1  444
9   1   x1  451
10   1   x1  458
11   1   x1  465
12   1   x1  473
13   1   x1  481
14   1   x1  484
15   1   x1  484
16   1   x1  482
17   1   x1  481
18   1   x1  480
19   1   x1  481
20   1   x1  479
1   2   x2  498
2   2   x2  498
3   2   x2  498
4   2   x2  501
5   2   x2  498
6   2   x2  498
7   2   x2  5000
8   2   x2  5021
9   2   x2  5025
10  2   x2  5022
11  2   x2  525
12  2   x2  533
13  2   x2  544
14  2   x2  544
15  2   x2  532
16  2   x2  520
17  2   x2  522
18  2   x2  525
19  2   x2  515
20  2   x2  5000
1   3   x3  3625
2   3   x3  3625
3   3   x3  3625
4   3   x3  3625
5   3   x3  3626
6   3   x3  3626
7   3   x3  3627
8   3   x3  3631
9   3   x3  3635
10  3   x3  3640
11  3   x3  3646
12  3   x3  3652
13  3   x3  3658
14  3   x3  3661
15  3   x3  3669
16  3   x3  3685
17  3   x3  3682
18  3   x3  3694
19  3   x3  5018
20  3   x3  3696
1   4   x4  3645
2   4   x4  3648
3   4   x4  3629
4   4   x4  3626
5   4   x4  3629
6   4   x4  3629
7   4   x4  3628
8   4   x4  3634
9   4   x4  3639
10  4   x4  3644
11  4   x4  3670
12  4   x4  3676
13  4   x4  3678
14  4   x4  3665
15  4   x4  3662
16  4   x4  3664
17  4   x4  3661
18  4   x4  3664
19  4   x4  3664
20  4   x4  3661
1   5   x5  5000
2   5   x5  5000
3   5   x5  5000
4   5   x5  5000
5   5   x5  5000
6   5   x5  5000
7   5   x5  5000
8   5   x5  5000
9   5   x5  5000
10  5   x5  5000
11  5   x5  5000
12  5   x5  5000
13  5   x5  5000
14  5   x5  5000
15  5   x5  2945
16  5   x5  2952
17  5   x5  2955
18  5   x5  2948
19  5   x5  2956
20  5   x5  2953
```

How would be the dynamic version of this? In the example I have 5 attributes, but Let´s say I do not know how many atrributes are there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm posting this, even though I'm upvoting @Martin's solution.  His is much more elegant (I've still to intuitively know when it's best to use PIVOT and UNPIVOT), but also more unforgiving, as the original tables' columns must be all the exact same data type and follow the "x####" naming convention.

Since I use more column substitution when building the query, I used `+ CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)` to add line breaks to the
dynamic SQL, in an attempt to make the code (both before and after) more legible.

```
DECLARE
  @TableName  sysname
 ,@Command    nvarchar(max)

SET @TableName = 'YourTable'

--  Build a big dynamic set of UNION SELECT statements
SELECT @Command = isnull(@Command + char(13) + char(10) + 'union all ', '')
  + 'select ' + cast(column_id as varchar(10)) + ' Ordinal, ''' + name + ''' name, ' + name + ' value ' + char(13) + char(10)
  + ' from ' + @TableName 
 from sys.columns
 where object_id = object_id(@TableName)

--  Wrap the above as a subquery, to enable the use of row_number()
SET @Command = 'select row_number() over (partition by Ordinal order by Ordinal) Id, Ordinal, Name, Value' + char(13) + char(10)
 + ' from (' + @Command + ') bigUnion'

--PRINT @Command
EXECUTE (@Command)
```

---

(Addenda)

Inserting the results of a dynamically created query into a temp table is fairly easy, so long as you don't have to dynamically create the temp table.

Temp tables only last for as long as the  “session” in which they are created. If created at the start of a stored procedure, they persist until that stored procedure (and any procedures it calls) is finished; if created within a dynamically created script, they persist until that script finishes. So you could build a “SELECT… INTO #…” dynamic script, teh table would be populated, and would then be dropped when that script finished execution. To persist the data longer than that, you’d have to create the temp table before calling the dynamic script, something like so:

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTempTable
 (
   Id
  ,Ordinal
  ,Name
  ,Value
 )
```

assigning the appropriate data types and nullability, and then populating it with

```
INSERT #MyTempTable (Id, Ordinal, Name, Value)
 EXECUTE (@Command)
```

Comment: Excuse me, And to store it into a temporal table, How would be like, before the `SELECT` do a `INSERT INTO #TEMP  SELECT...`?

Comment: Added a second section to my reply.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @DynSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @DynSQL = ISNULL(@DynSQL+ ',','') + QUOTENAME(name) 
FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID('dbo.YourTable')

SET @DynSQL = '
;WITH T AS
(
SELECT *, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS Id
FROM YourTable)
SELECT Id,
       CAST(SUBSTRING(Name,2,10) AS INT) AS Ordinal,
       Name,
       Value
FROM T
UNPIVOT(Value for Name in (' + @DynSQL + ')) U 
ORDER BY Ordinal,Id'

EXEC(@DynSQL)
```